# Implementing Single User Per Page concept in J2EE web application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Are there patterns for implementing a single user per page model in a J2EE environment?

By single user per page I mean, if I access:

```
mysite.com/foo/pageA
```

If someone else tries to access this page, they should not be able to until I:

```
-navigate away from the page
-close the browser
```

As it stands now, I have implemented this feature using a map that is a member variable in the servlet that handles requests for `foo/*`. The keys for the map are page names (enum), and the values for the maps are a boolean value that represents whether or not that particular page is locked.

Before the page is served, I look at the map value to determine if the page is occuiped, and if it is not, I send the user to the page and update the map entry (synchronizing on the map), if it is , I send the user to a page displaying the message that the page is occupied.

To implement the locking, I use the onbeforeunload javascript method, in which I use an ajax post call to update the map entry to false, again, synchronizing on the map.

I know that if the application expands to more than one instance, the locking/unlocking will have to be persisted, but as it stands now, the application only serves about 10 users.

It seems to be working, but I was wondering if there were established patterns for accomplishing this, or if the idea of locking a page to only allow a single user is bad practice in a web application.

Comment: The requirement doesn't make sense to me, but if you ever hope to support the application with more than one servlet instance the "lock" will have to be persisted outside the JVM.

Comment: Note that 'onbeforeunload' is not 100% reliable (Browser crashes). So you'll need some kind of timeout. As an idea: Java EE transaction management might also provide the locking.